How to get rid of black reflections on the underside of an ocean modifier
I created an ocean modifier from a plane then applied a refraction node to the ocean with the intent to make an underwater scene but it creates some black reflections depending on the angle of the camera. How do I fix it?
These are the ocean modifier settings:


Is there anything black in your scene (objects, environment) ? Also, a plane object is a bad idea if you want to have realistic water : it should be a cube, an object with volume. Is your camera inside the water, or outside ?

There isnt anything black just the surface and a clear HDRI. I was first just going to make the surface as I was following a video, but I follow the same steps as him and he doesnt have this issue. Ill link the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OeQfq-Sc-lM
